# Conceptual ownership vs temporary shared access with `unique_ptr` / `shared_ptr`

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, ownership-semantics

I've spent a decade away from C++, and now I'm confused about `unique_ptr`.

tl;dr I find that in some cases I conceptually want unique ownership, but I'm forced to use `shared_ptr` for technical reasons. Worse still, I'm forced to use `shared_ptr` because of unforeseeable client needs, which kinda leads to *always* using shared instead of unique. And that feels wrong.

Assume we have a `Car` class, where each `Car` owns some `Wheel`s. In our model this is full, unique ownership; the `Wheel`s have no way to outlive the `Car`, when the `Car` is destructed, all of its `Wheel`s are destructed too. At least conceptually. On the surface it seems like a clear-cut case for `unique_ptr`.

However, we would like to be able to construct a list of `Wheel`s (owner either by `Car`s or other wheeled things), and pass that list to a function that computes something about `Wheel`s. What would be the type of that list? It can't be `weak_ptr`s, because, well, we can't get a `weak_ptr` out of a `unique_ptr`, but also, we'd then need to `lock()` that `weak_ptr`, practically creating a second owner, violating unique ownership (temporarily).

Technicalities aside, in a more general sense, how do we pass around objects owned by a `unique_ptr`? The receiver might want to lock the object (eg. because it's running on a different thread), but that sort of violates unique ownership, at least temporarily. But this second "ownership" **isn't real ownership**, it's more like just "hey, I don't own this thing, but I'm working with it, so please don't destruct it until I'm finished". From a technical point of view, sure, this is shared ownership, but conceptually it's a very different thing. How do we express this difference in C++? Do we? Or do we just go with the technical and call it shared, even if it really isn't (or only in a very limited sense), and with the words of my poetic buddy ChatGPT "conceptually muddle the ownership semantics"?

Even more importantly, when I add a new member to a class, it's pretty easy to tell if it's *conceptually* a uniquely owned subobject or not; but how do I know if clients of my class will ever need to assume temporary *technical* ownership of it?

At this point it seems to me that the safe bet is just to always use `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr` for class members (possibly with the exception of private members). Maybe add an alias to mark unique ownership (only shared temporarily with workers). (Though it would be real nice if I could also specialize some templates differently for the case of "unique ownership, just using `shared_ptr` because of potential workers".)

So anyway, what are the best practices around `unique_ptr` as class member and passing around things owned by `unique_ptr`s? What books / articles should I go and read?

Comment: Can you guarantee that the *car* outlives the (parallel) process on the *wheel*s? In that case, you can `get` the underlying pointer and pass it(preferably wrapped in some custom *observer pointer* with 0 chance of `delete`ing) around.

Comment: I think often you just don't want ownership to be enforced by pointers - you should already be able to know that the receiver outlives the car, and thus pass a regular pointer/reference to the wheels. However, one trick you can with shared_ptr is that if you have a `shared_ptr` to a car, you can create a `shared_ptr` to *any part of the car* (number 8 in [this list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)) even though the parts may not be shared_ptrs themselves

Comment: What you describe sounds like *borrowing*. Borrowing an object is one of the last remaining valid uses of raw pointers. You just have to be clear in the semantics that the borrowed pointer has a limited lifetime. So a `vector<Wheel*>` is fine, as long as it's just for a function call or two, not for creating a long-lived data structure

Comment: You can also use the [aliasing constructor of `shared_ptr`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27109379/what-is-shared-ptrs-aliasing-constructor-for). In your example, the car would be owned by a `shared_ptr` (probably with `enable_shared_from_this`), the wheels are `unique_ptrs`, and you can create a `shared_ptr<Wheel>` that extends the lifetime of the car until the pointer to the wheel is destroyed

Comment: There is still [observer_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/observer_ptr) to be explicit about non-owning to replace raw pointer.

Comment: If you want lifetime guaranty in addition to ownership, then indeed, `std::unique_ptr`+raw/observer pointer is out; `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` does the job.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45087944/how-to-indicate-c-ownership-of-pointer

Comment: The point about smart pointers is you should only use them to manage the lifetime of the object they point to and you should not be passing them to functions unless you want to transfer ownership to that function. Most of the time you should be passing *raw pointers* that are managed by a smart pointer higher up in the call stack.

Comment: Typically, most of your smart pointers should probably be `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` should preferably be few and far between.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25705417/use-of-raw-pointers-in-modern-c-post-c11

Comment: Use smart pointers to manage lifetime, use raw pointer to express "no lifetime management". This often corresponds with model semantics (like a car with wheels), but doesn't have to. Also have a look at the related [core guideline](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#r30-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to summarize the comments and links provided in comments (thanks everyone!). Note I may still be wrong, further comments are welcome.

While there are ways to get a `shared_ptr` to an object owned by a `unique_ptr` (see shared_ptr's aliasing constructor), generally it's better to pass such objects to functions as `T*` or `T&` parameters (most importantly see https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-smart).

This is good advice, though it might be (was for me) a bit non-trivial to see why it's safe.

My initial reaction to this advice was "how would this work in a multithreaded environment"? It's very hard to guarantee that while a function running on one thread is working with an object, that object won't get destructed on another thread. This seems to mean that the function does need to extend the object's lifetime (though I'm still reluctant to call this "ownership").

However, the function does *not* need to extend the object's lifetime if someone up the call chain already has ownership of the object -- which is almost always the case, with the exception of passing the object across threads. In all other cases passing `T*` or `T&` is the way to go.

When calling across threads, we do need to pass `shared_ptr`. (Of course we can't do that if we only have a `T*`, so a second case of a function needing to take a `shared_ptr` param is a function that itself may later need to pass the object across threads.) In the case of passing a uniquely owned subobject across threads, we can either pass a shared_ptr to the parent object, or use `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor (creating a `shared_ptr` that points at the subobject, but extends the lifetime of the parent).

One case to consider is passing a subobject `s` of a parent `p` from a function `f()` to another function `g()` on a  thread that is different from the one that conceptually owns `p`. Passing as `T*` or `T&` is still fine, because when we passed `p` across threads (eg. when calling `f()`), we passed it as `shared_ptr`. If `f()` has a `shared_ptr` to `p`, then it can safely pass `s` to `g()` as `T*` or `T&`, `f()`'s `shared_ptr` will guarantee that `s` won't be destructed while `g()` (more precisely while `f()`) is running, regardless of what the conceptual owner thread of `p` is doing.